# Spring Boot: how to run a server at Spring Context startup and stop it during context shutdown during execution of tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

My Spring Boot application uses a database server. During the tests, I would like to run an embedded version of the database. The server starts with a random port each time (it's from `testcontainers.org`).

First thing I tried was to use JUnit4's `@ClassRule` to start/stop the server, but Spring Boot is smart and re-uses contexts across test classes. So for a single test class everything works fine, but when I run tests in a package (or all tests), they fail due to this lifecycle difference.

1. Is it possible to somehow hook into tests execution and get a callback when Spring Boot Test infrastructure starts and stops a new context?

The most probable answer I will get is 'just add a server bean to the context when your tests run'. Ok, but here I face another problem:

2. How do I make sure that the server bean is initialized before other beans that talk to the server? `@DependsOn` does not seem to fit here as I do not want to have in production a bean annotated with `@DependsOn("testServer")`

Spring Boot is 2.1.6.

Comment: can you pls elaborate the lifecycle difference? do you have the error stacktrace?